# Using switch case for bitwise enums

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, bitwise-operators

I have implemented my own typesafe bitwise enum operators following this article: http://blog.bitwigglers.org/using-enum-classes-as-type-safe-bitmasks/

Here is the enum I am talking about:

```
enum class OutputStream : unsigned int
    {
        None = 0,
        // Using bitshift operator (always one bit set to 1)
        Console = 1 << 0,
        File = 1 << 1,
        Other = 1 << 2
    };
```

In case you wonder, it's for a logging function.

**Problem:**
I want to use the enum in a switch statement such as

```
switch(stream)
{
    case OutputStream::Console:
        //Do this
    case OutputStream::File:
        //Do that
    default:
        break;
}
```

Note that there shouldn't be a `break;` in between the case statements since more than one case can be true.

**However**, this doesn't seem to work. More precisely, when I use `OutputStream::Console | OutputStream::File` neither case is executed.

My only solution to this problem was this awkward looking if statement:

```
if((stream & OutputStream::Console) != OutputStream::None) { /*Do this*/ }
if((stream & OutputStream::File) != OutputStream::None) { /*Do that*/ }
```

But for me, this defeats the point of a need enum based solution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `switch` is not the appropriate tool for this problem.  It will not test a particular bit of a value.  Use `if` statements.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is posting isolated chunks of code that fail to meet the requirements of a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Comment: Enumerations are not very good for use as bit fields.

Comment: The `switch` will fail, because `OutputStream::Console | OutputStream::File` is neither exactly `OutputStream::Console` nor exactly `OutputStream::File`. For a `case` to be selected, it must be equal to the `switch` statement. In any case, `case` fallthrough is sequential. Subsequent `case` labels aren't rechecked to see if some condition is true. It just runs through the `case` labels as if they weren't there. I'm not sure how you imagine `switch` works, but it's clear there is a significant misunderstanding.

Comment: Are `Console` and `File` mutually exclusive conditions? Or can any combination of either occur?

Comment: FWIW `if((stream & OutputStream::Console) != OutputStream::None)` can just be `if(stream & OutputStream::Console)`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok that makes sense. So Console | File would be 3u which is neither 2u nor 1u and therefore it falls through both switches. I did indeed think switch worked differently

Comment: @NathanOliver  That's what I thought. But no, the compiler complains since there is no implicit conversion to unsigned int when using C++ 11s enum classes as suppose to C's enums

Comment: @AdrianKoch Consider using a regular sequential `enum` and using an [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead.

Comment: @AdrianKoch Oops.  Missed you were using an enum class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other said in comments, switch is not the best way, but it is still possible to do:

```
for (int bit = 1; bit <= (int) OutputStream::LAST; bit <<= 1)
{
    switch((OutputStream) (bit & stream))
    {
        case OutputStream::Console:
            //Do this
            break;
        case OutputStream::File:
            //Do that
            break;

        // etc...

        // no default case no case 0!
    }
}
```

So basically you will iterate over all individual bits, for each test if it is present in the `stream` variable and jump to the appropriate `case`, or jump nowhere if it is 0.

But in my opinion the individual ifs are better. At least you have better control over in which order are the bits evaluated.